# Thread gets killed after few iterations

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to create an application which contains a service that starts when device boots up & then logs some events.

**Service entry in manifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name="com.myservices.BReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.myservices.MyService" >
</service>
```

**BReceiver.java**

```
public class BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive started");
        // Main Logging Service
        Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(service);
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive ended");
    }

}
```

**MService.class**

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private static final long TIMER = 2000;

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        startLogginThread();

    }

    /**
     * For logging
     */
    private void startLogginThread() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {

                        // Logging events
                        myLogger();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Awake");
                        // TIMER
                        Thread.sleep(TIMER);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("MyService", "local Thread error "+ e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void myLogger() {

        // Creating new file to store logs.
        // Check if SD card is available else use internal memory.
        File dir = null;
        if (MyServiceUtil.isExternalStorageReadable() && MyServiceUtil.isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            // External Memory
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyLogger");
            dir.mkdirs();
        } else {
            // Internal Memory
            dir = getFilesDir();
        }

        // Rename to txt for reading
        File file = new File(dir, "log.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception :" + e.toString());
            }
        }

        // Printing timestamp in file
        try {

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy '-' HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            out.println(timeStamp);

            // Log Location

            out.close();
            Log.e("Logggging", timeStamp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception :" + e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy called");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**Result:**
Only a few times, like 6-7 times the log is printed & stored in the file.
Below is the log:

```
11-16 17:00:02.438: E/BReceiver(3187): onReceive started
11-16 17:00:02.438: E/BReceiver(3187): onReceive ended
11-16 17:00:02.458: E/MyService(3187): onDestroy called
11-16 17:00:02.458: D/MyServiceUtil(3187): isExternalStorageReadable started
11-16 17:00:02.468: D/MyServiceUtil(3187): isExternalStorageWritable started
11-16 17:00:02.468: E/Logggging(3187): 16.11.2014 - 17:00:02
11-16 17:00:02.468: E/MyService(3187): Awake
11-16 17:00:04.468: D/MyServiceUtil(3187): isExternalStorageReadable started
11-16 17:00:04.468: D/MyServiceUtil(3187): isExternalStorageWritable started
11-16 17:00:04.478: E/Logggging(3187): 16.11.2014 - 17:00:04
11-16 17:00:04.478: E/MyService(3187): Awake
11-16 17:00:06.478: D/MyServiceUtil(3187): isExternalStorageReadable started
11-16 17:00:06.488: D/MyServiceUtil(3187): isExternalStorageWritable started
11-16 17:00:06.488: E/Logggging(3187): 16.11.2014 - 17:00:06
11-16 17:00:06.488: E/MyService(3187): Awake
11-16 17:00:08.488: D/MyServiceUtil(3187): isExternalStorageReadable started
11-16 17:00:08.488: D/MyServiceUtil(3187): isExternalStorageWritable started
11-16 17:00:08.488: E/Logggging(3187): 16.11.2014 - 17:00:08
11-16 17:00:08.488: E/MyService(3187): Awake
```

Also, I do not understand why, onDestroy is called, if the thread in already running:

11-16 17:00:02.458: E/MyService(3187): onDestroy called

PS - This is only occurring in Kitkat.

Comment: Can you try catching Throwable instead of Exception, you could be getting an error.  If you do this, only catch the error once, or you could go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Is there any commitment in the Android JVM that activities with running threads do not get killed no matter how low memory or other condition?

Answer (score 1):

To do a background task in BroadcastReceiver you need to call [goAsync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync()), sdk 11+, and upon finish call PendingResult.finish()

> This can be called by an application in onReceive(Context, Intent) to
>   allow it to keep the broadcast active after returning from that
>   function. This does not change the expectation of being relatively
>   responsive to the broadcast (finishing it within 10s), but does allow
>   the implementation to move work related to it over to another thread
>   to avoid glitching the main UI thread due to disk IO.

You can either move your code in the receiver and use *goAsync* or run your code directly in the IntentService because it is not like Service, it has it is own background thread.

**Update**

```
final PendingResult pendingResult = goAsync();

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (SOME_CONDITION) {
            try {
                // Logging events
                myLogger();
                Log.e(TAG, "Awake");
                // TIMER
                Thread.sleep(TIMER);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyService", "local Thread error "+ e.toString());
            }
        }

        // Finish the broadcast.
        pendingResult.finish();
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: thanks, but I don not understand how to use goAsync()'s pending intent. Should I just call goAsync() in my Breceiver? Please update ur answer with e.g. if possible

Answer (score 1):

you dont understand the IntentService very well . The method of onHandleIntent was called in a sub thread which the framework started, this Service will kill itself when the onHandleIntent was completed , therefor he reason is that you put the job in a new thread which you started . So, ou should put code into the onHandleIntent.

```
while (true) {
  try {

     // Logging events
     myLogger();
     Log.e(TAG, "Awake");
     // TIMER
     Thread.sleep(TIMER);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("MyService", "local Thread error "+ e.toString());
  }
}
```